# Can i use MongoDB in my graphQL server without the use of prisma?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, express-graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to use mongodb queries directly without the prisma. Is it possible? If possible, is this a good practice and will i be able to use all the functionalities of graphql, Like cursor based pagination and others?

Comment: Please give us as much specific info as possible related to your requirements.  This question in its current state is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Prisma documentation, you currently can't directly access the database through Prisma:

> - **rawAccess:** Specifies whether the executeRaw mutation will be enabled in the Prisma API. The MongoDB connector currently doesn't support raw access, so you need to set this to false or omit it.

Source: https://www.prisma.io/docs/releases-and-maintenance/releases-and-beta-access/mongodb-preview-b6o5/#prisma_config